# replace _asm nop in 64-bit, VS2008, C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

How to replace `_asm nop` instructions in 64-bit. compiles and works in 32-bit.

Comment: I think the most of us need a little bit more context...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that you can use the __nop intrinsic function.  This should compile into the appropriate machine instruction for the processor that you are building.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983381(VS.80).aspx

UPDATE:

Here is an example that I just created with VS2008.  It compiles for both Win32 and x64 configurations:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <intrin.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // The intrinsic function below will compile to a NOP machine instruction.
    // This is the same as _asm nop in the 32-bit compiler.
    __nop();
    return 0;
}
```

In case you are wondering, I disassembled the above example and the x64 output was:

```
wmain    proc near
         db    66h
         nop
         nop
         xor   eax, eax
         retn
wmain    endp
```

The Win32 output was:

```
_main    proc near
        nop
        xor    eax, eax
        retn
_main   endp
```

Comment: And what is the error?  Did you #include <intrin.h> like the doc says?  I tried this with VS2008 and it compiled fine.

Comment: Ah, ok, the problem was that I was not including <intrin.h> header file...thanks for posting the sample code..

Answer (score 1):

You can't use _asm in a 64-bit program.  The replacement is intrinsics, a list of instructions is [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zs5twb.aspx).  NOP isn't one of them, you'd have to use [MASM64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb5z4sxd.aspx), available as vc\bin\x86_amd64\ml64.exe when you've got the 64-bit compilers installed.

Comment: ok, but it's inside C++, it compiles in VC++ 2008, I don't understand how am I suppose to use MASAM64 for this,..

Comment: I'll put it another way: you cannot use inline assembly with _asm if you want to compile to x64.  Post your _asm code to help us help you.